# Error when adding element to list of objects

Tags: c#, list, object

I wish to dynamically create and save objects to a list. When program reachs the `add` method to add objects in the list I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What have I done wrong here?

```
List<Category> categoryList;

public Main(string firstname, string lastname, string status)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.Text = (firstname + lastname + status).Trim();

    string connection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Trgovina.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);

    try
    {
        cn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("Error occurred during database communication!"); }

    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Kategorije_art";
    SqlCommand categoryCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cn);
    SqlDataReader categoryDataRead = categoryCommand.ExecuteReader();

    categoryList.Add(new Category(1, "a")); //ERROR ?!
}
```

Comment: Well where do you initialize `categoryList`? I can't see anything assigning it a value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net/4660186#4660186

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to actually create `List` instance

```
List<Category> categoryList= new List<Category>();
```

In the first line.

Answer (score 4):

Your member, categoryList, is not initialised.

Try:

```
List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();

public Main(string firstname, string lastname, string status)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.Text = (firstname+lastname+status).Trim();

    string connection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Trgovina.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);

    try 
    {
        cn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("Error occurred during database communication!"); }

    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Kategorije_art";
    SqlCommand categoryCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cn);
    SqlDataReader categoryDataRead = categoryCommand.ExecuteReader();

    categoryList.Add(new Category(1, "a")); //ERROR ?!
}
```

Also note you should probably have your SqlConnection in a using block, or at least call Close/Dispose on it so you aren't leaking connections.

Comment: I'd be interested to know who voted this down, and why...seems legit to me!

Answer (score 2):

Your `categoryList` is not initialized. Change your first line to:

```
List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();
```

The null reference exception is coming when you try to access the `.Add(...)` method on a null value.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable named `categoryList` is not initialized. So it is null.

You can't call any method on a unitialized variable.

Try :

```
List<Category> categoryList= new List<Category>();
```

Answer (score 1):

do you create `categoryList = new List<Category>()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your error line should look like this:

```
categoryList = new List<Category>() { new Category(1,"a")};
```

so You create list and add one created element and store reference to this list in `categoryList`